# Dynamic modification of grid-template-rows

Tags: css, sass, layout, css-grid, grid-layout

I have a React component with this structure
the tools and searchPanel blocks have fixed heights.
the main block should occupy the remaining space:

```
    <div className={`reference-container`}> 
        {
         isToolsVisible && <div className={`tools`}></div>
        }
        {
         isSeracpPanleVisible && <div className={`searchPanel`}></div>
        }
        <div className={`mainContent`}></div>
    </div>
```

I have a stylesheet file:

```
.reference-container {
    $toolHeight: 100px;
    $serachPanelHeight: 50px;
    
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "tools"
      "serachPanel"
      "mainContent";
    grid-template-rows: $toolHeight $serachPanelHeight 1fr;
    
    .tools {
        grid-area: tools
    }
    .searchPanel {
        grid-area: searchPanel
    }
    .mainContent {
        grid-area: mainContent
    }
}
```

Depending on the *condition*,  and  are *displayed*.
However, I'm not sure how to correctly change ***grid-template-areas*** when the conditional blocks are absent.

I tried to set several conditional modifier classes for the parent container, and based on them, dynamically define the grid-template in the CSS file.

*html(JSX)*

```
<div className={`reference-container ${isToolsVisible ? 'with-tools' : ''} ${isSearchPanelVisible ? 'with-search-panel' : ''}`}>
  {isToolsVisible && <div className={`tools`}></div>}
  {isSearchPanelVisible && <div className={`searchPanel`}></div>}
  <div className={`mainContent`}></div>
</div>
```

*SCSS*

```
.reference-container {
  $toolHeight: 100px;
  $searchPanelHeight: 50px;

  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  
  &.with-tools {
    grid-template-areas: 
      "tools"
      "mainContent";
    grid-template-rows: $toolHeight 1fr;
  }
  
  &.with-search-panel {
    grid-template-areas: 
      "searchPanel"
      "mainContent";
    grid-template-rows: $searchPanelHeight 1fr;
  }
  
  .tools {
    grid-area: tools;
  }
  
  .searchPanel {
    grid-area: searchPanel;
  }
  
  .mainContent {
    grid-area: mainContent;
  }
}
```

I think this is not the correct solution, maybe it's better not to use grid at all in this case?please advise a better one. Thank u advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it too complicated.

The elements in the HTML are in the same order that you want them to be seen, you can let the grid-flow take care of this. You only need to set the main content to the last row:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
    margin: 5px;
}

.tools {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.search {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.main {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-row: -2 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="tools"></div>
<div class="search"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="search"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="tools"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is height: 100% specified for main?

Comment: You are right, it is not needed; I have updated the snippet

Answer (score 0):

I was also advised elsewhere that it's better to use Flexbox here.
In my opinion, a simpler and more refined solution in this specific case is as follows.

```
.reference-container {
  $toolHeight: 100px;
  $searchPanelHeight: 50px;

  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;


  .tools {
    height: $toolHeight;
  }

  .searchPanel {
    height: $searchPanelHeight;
  }

  .mainContent {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```